# billboard.js custom index label

Tags: jquery, charts, billboard.js

I'm trying to achieve the goal of having a custom index label instead of his 0-n cardinal, the y axis rightly shows the scale values and the x axis use a timeline progression who I need to use to describe the chart point which you have currently selected with you mouse, just to be sure instead of 0-n cardinal I want to show 2021-01-01, 2021-01-02, 2021-01-05 etc the day which have been stored data. I'm seeking in the doc but I'm not sure what I have to find, actually I found the event onover and I'm trying to update like this:

```
onover: function(d, element) { d['x'] = ajax_result['data'][d['index']]['My_Index'] }
```

but I'm having tons of errors that lure me to figure out editing of object not yet created, sometime NaN on the object lenght some other time expected number on d
Any better idea?

Comment: https://github.com/naver/billboard.js/issues/284

Comment: https://github.com/naver/billboard.js/issues/1021

Comment: My scenario is a bit different: my input json contains a data for each row. This is a real sample: 
{
    "Index": "2021-10-19",
    "Count": "5538",
    "Count_OK": "5153",
    "Count_KO": "385",
    "Count_KPI": "0"
}